# Populate dropdown with fields from database with no duplicates?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<li>
<label>Manufacturer</label>
<select name="brand">
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT CarMake FROM cars");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['CarMake'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

My only issue is the `CarMake` field has manufacturers listed more than once i.e. BMW is listed more than once so what is happening is obviously BMW is displayed more than once in the dropdown. Is there any way to get the manufacturers to display in alphabetical order and only once each?

Is there a way to add in an `Any` option to the dropdown so that the user can choose to search by any make rather than a specific one or can this not be done?

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` like `SELECT DISTINCT CarMake FROM cars`

Comment: ... and an `order by` clause as well.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid  
Is there a way to add in an `Any` option to the dropdown so that the user can choose to search by any make rather than a specific one? Also the issue I'm having is that when selecting options from the dropdown box and clicking `Search`, it's POSTing `owner1`as the value rather than the actual manufacturer name chosen from the dropdown. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT CarMake FROM cars ORDER BY CarMake ASC");
```

Comment: Is there a way to add in an Any option to the dropdown so that the user can choose to search by any make rather than a specific one?

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>
<label>Manufacturer</label>
<select name="brand">
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT distinct CarMake FROM cars order by CarMake");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['CarMake'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there a way to add in an Any option to the dropdown so that the user can choose to search by any make rather than a specific one?

Comment: In order to add 'any' option to drop down you will have to put `<option value="any">ANY</option>";` right after your `<select name="brand">`. Then in your code before doing the query, do an if statement that will check the value, and if it is any, it will run select * query, instead it will run your customized one.